# $99$th derivative of $\sin x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Can someone help me calculate the $99$th derivative of $\sin(x)$?

Calculate $f^{(99)}(x) $ for the function $f(x) = \sin(x) $

Comment: Did you want the $99^{th}$ derivative of $\sin(x)$? Because that is usually denoted as $f^{(99)}(x)$

Comment: In the question, it just says the second line.

Answer (score 15):

Notice if $f(x) = \sin x$

$f'(x) = \cos x = \sin( x + \frac{\pi}{2}) $

$f''(x) = - \sin x = \sin( x + \pi) = \sin( x + 2 (\frac{\pi}{2})) $

$f'''(x) = - \cos x = \sin(x + 3( \frac{\pi}{2} ))$

$f''''(x) = \sin x $

Hence, we can say that

$$ f^{(n)} (x) = \sin \left( x + n \cdot\frac{\pi}{2} \right) $$

Comment: Yes, How can I use this information to find $f^{(n)}(x)$?

Comment: editted my answer

Comment: Prove by induction that the cycle continues? I think it's obvious enough since the next term only depends on the last.

Comment: (+1) Very nice relation! I've never seen it expressed like that.

Answer (score 8):

We have

$$\left(\sin x\right)^{(k)}=\sin\left( x+k\frac\pi2\right)$$

and recall that the $\sin$ function is $2\pi$ periodic.

Comment: (+1) twice for one question. I've never seen this expressed in this way before (except in Lemur's answer). Very nice.

Comment: Very nice Sami. This made me to make it favorited for myself.

Answer (score 6):

Note that given $f(x)=\sin x,$

\begin{align}
& f'(x)=\cos x\\
& f''(x)=-\sin x\\
& f'''(x)=-\cos x\\
& f^{(4)}(x)=\sin x
\end{align}

Why is this important? Well, note that after taking the derivative of $\sin x$ four times, we are back at $\sin x$. So, we can conclude that for $f(x)=\sin x,$

\begin{align}
 f(x)=f^{(4)}(x)=f^{(8)}(x)=\ldots=f^{(96)}(x)=\sin x
\end{align}

So given that $f^{(96)}(x)=\sin x$, then $f^{(97)}(x)=\cos x, f^{(98)}(x)=-\sin x, f^{(99)}(x)=-\cos x.$

If you are familiar with integration, you also can note that $f(x)=\sin x=f^{(100)}(x)$, and so $f^{(99)}(x)=\int\sin x=-\cos x$.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know modular arithmetic? Notice from the first few derivatives,

- $f(x)=\sin(x)$
- $f'(x)=\cos(x)$
- $f''(x)=-\sin(x)$
- $f'''(x)=-\cos(x)$
- $f^{(4)}(x)=\sin(x)$

Therefore, we have that

$f^{(n)}(x) = \left\{ \begin{array} \. \sin(x), & n \equiv 0 (\mod 4)\\
\cos(x), & n \equiv 1 (\mod 4)\\
 -\sin(x), & n \equiv 2 (\mod 4)\\
- \cos(x), & n \equiv 3 (\mod 4).
\end{array} \right.$

So, notice that $99 \div 4=24$ with remainder $3$. Therefore, $f^{(99)}(x)=-\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

${{d^{4n}}\over{dx^{4n}}}(\sin x)=\sin{x}$
${{d^{4n+1}}\over{dx^{4n+1}}}(\sin x)=\cos{x}$
${{d^{4n+2}}\over{dx^{4n+2}}}(\sin x)=-\sin{x}$
${{d^{4n+3}}\over{dx^{4n+3}}}(\sin x)=-\cos{x}$
Pick the one that you think might be useful :-)